# Server does not respond to concurrent requests in HTTP/1.1 Client using Java

Tags: java, client-server, http-1.1

I'am trying to implement a simple HTTP/1.1 client application against a remote HTTP server. If  I have a `301 Moved Permanently` response from server, I will try to download the file from it's new location given in server's response. I am able to send first `GET` message to server and retrieve the new URL where the file I asked was moved.

The problem is that when I send second `GET` request from my client with new location of the file, server returns `null`. Not sure if anything goes wrong with writing the client message or reading the server response. Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
else if(serverMessage.equals("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"))
{
     System.out.println(" A new permanent URL is assigned to the file " + fileName);
     serverMessage="";
     lineCount=0;
     while((serverMessage = reader.readLine()) != null)
     {          
         lineCount++;
         System.out.println("reply: " + serverMessage);
         if(serverMessage.indexOf("Location") >= 0 )
         {
              for(int x=serverMessage.indexOf("Location")+10; x<serverMessage.length(); x++)
              {
                      newURL= newURL + serverMessage.charAt(x); 
              }
          }
                            
      }
     System.out.println("newURL : " + newURL);
     host = findHost(newURL);
                        
     path = findPath(newURL);
                        
     fileName=findFileName(newURL);                   
                        
     clientMessage = "GET ";
     clientMessage = clientMessage + path;
     clientMessage = clientMessage + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ";
     clientMessage = clientMessage + host;
     clientMessage = clientMessage + "\r\n\r\n";
                        
     System.out.println("client message: \"" + clientMessage +"\"");

     writer.newLine();
     writer.write(clientMessage);
     writer.flush();

     serverMessage = reader.readLine();
     System.out.println("reply2: " + serverMessage); //returns null!!!
                        
     while((serverMessage=reader.readLine())!=null)
     {
           System.out.println("reply2: " + serverMessage);
     }
                        
}
```

**EDIT:** Variables of client message are the followings (they all work correctly, tested for existing file - successfully downloaded!)

newURL : [http://wlab.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~cs421/pa1/302-redirect-success.txt](http://wlab.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Ecs421/pa1/302-redirect-success.txt)
host2: wlab.cs.bilkent.edu.tr
path2: /~cs421/pa1/302-redirect-success.txt
fileName2: 302-redirect-success.txt

Comment: Can you please post what the clientMessage variable contains?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a persistent `URLConnection` / `HttpURLConnection`?

You may be receiving `null` if the connection has been closed by the server.

If you are using persistent connections, the server might have not had the time to respond.

[This](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-open-url-read-contents-httpurl-connection-java) might describe the problem a little better. Check out the timeout given in `doHttpUrlConnectionAction(String desiredUrl)`. You might find the answer there.

If this is your problem, you can try to do multiple reads at 0.1 second intervals for say ... 1-5 seconds. This is to make sure you get the response fast and don't have to wait the full timeout to make sure that the server has responded.